# Replacing attribute value in XSLT

Tags: xslt, templates, attributes

I am trying to perform an XSL Transformation. But an attribute replacement doesn't work. I have this XSL:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:output encoding="UTF-8"
doctype-public="-//WAPFORUM//DTD WML 1.1//EN"
doctype-system="http://www.wapforum.org/DTD/wml_1.1.xml"/>

<xsl:template match="/">

<wml xml:lang="da">
<card id="FrontPage" title="{head/title}">
Why doesn't the title get inserted?

<p id="changed">The server processed this Jan 1st. 2009.</p>
</card></wml>
</xsl:template></xsl:stylesheet>
```

And the XML that will be transformed is an XHTML 1.0 Transitional document. The document naturally contains a html/head/title element. I want the text content of the title element inserted into the title attribute of the card element:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
  "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
  <head>
    <title>DMI - The weather on Faroe Islands</title>
(...)
```

I use PHP 5.2.0 and libxslt version 1.1.19.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is two problems:

```
<xsl:template match="/">
  <wml xml:lang="da">
     <card id="FrontPage" title="{html/head/title}">
```

The document root ("/") isn't the `<html>` element. It's *before* the `<html>` element.

Additionally, as divo correctly points out, you are missing the XHTML namespace:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  xmlns:x="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
  exclude-result-prefixes="x"
>

  <xsl:output 
    encoding="UTF-8" 
    doctype-public="-//WAPFORUM//DTD WML 1.1//EN"
    doctype-system="http://www.wapforum.org/DTD/wml_1.1.xml"
  />

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <wml xml:lang="da">
      <card id="FrontPage" title="{x:html/x:head/x:title}">
        <p id="changed">The server processed this Jan 1st. 2009.</p>
      </card>
    </wml>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 1):

You are missing the html namespace declaration. Try the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
                xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
                xmlns:xhtml="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

  <xsl:output encoding="UTF-8"
              doctype-public="-//WAPFORUM//DTD WML 1.1//EN"
              doctype-system="http://www.wapforum.org/DTD/wml_1.1.xml"
              indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="/">

    <wml xml:lang="da">
      <card id="FrontPage" title="{xhtml:html/xhtml:head/xhtml:title}">
        <p id="changed">The server processed this Jan 1st. 2009.</p>
      </card>
    </wml>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Note that you may change the prefix from `xhtml` to anything shorter that you like.

There has been another smaller problem also (which is probably based on a common misunderstanding): `/` means the document root which is not the same as the top-most node in the document (`html`). The top-most node is often called "root node" which is not correct, i.e. `/` does not match the top-most node. Therefore `xhtml:html` has to be added to the XPath expression.

Answer (score 0):

Change your template match expression to `/html`:

```
<xsl:template match="/html">
```